# Visual C++ System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog() throws System.AccessViolationException and quietly kills application if started by drag/drop

Tags: c++, .net, windows

In a simple application (a skeleton put together with Visual Studio designer) I recently worked around an error that only manifests if I use drag/drop to execute the program.

Problem: I drag and drop a file onto my program.  I later use File->SaveAs to save the contents of a rich text box.  If I attempt to type a filename or drop down the hierarchy of directory paths, the application instantly quits.  If I select a file displayed in the SaveAs dialog, this works fine (after accepting the overwrite).

Workaround: Add a try/catch block above the ShowDialog call in the saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click function containing an attempt to open and write to a file.  A simple fputs will cause the exception, which I then ignore and delete any file created in the process.

If someone knows a simpler (or cleaner!) solution, thanks in advance.  Otherwise, here is my ugly solution:

```
private: System::Void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    static bool fFirstTime = true;
    static char *sBogusFileName = "c:\\__$$TrashFileIMustCreateThenDelete";
    SaveFileDialog^ dialog = gcnew SaveFileDialog();
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult DR;
        dialog->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        dialog->FilterIndex = 2;
        dialog->RestoreDirectory = true;
//        dialog->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

        if (fFirstTime)
        {
            FILE *fp;

            // This is a strange problem that came up on my Windows XP machine.
            // The first time through this logic, I would get a System.AccessViolationException
            // If I do it with this simple fputs, the error is recoverable.
            // If it happens during the dialog->ShowDialog that follows, the application quietly exits.
            // No event logs, nothing.  This solved it for me.
            try {
                // The fopen that follows make the MS compiler unhappy.  The filename is hard-coded, so I don't care.
                #pragma warning( suppress: 4996 )
                fp=fopen(sBogusFileName, "w");
                fputs("A string that might never be actually written - this causes an exception on some machines\n", fp);
            }
            catch(Exception ^e)
            {
                (void)e;    // Suppress another compiler error (unused variable)
                // Debug code that I later removed.  This logging is not required to fix the problem.
                // RRCLOGB1("\nError attempting to write to a file:\n%s\n\n", e->ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                fclose(fp);
            }
            remove(sBogusFileName);

            fFirstTime = false;        // Only cause the exception once...but why is it necessary?!?
        }

        DR = dialog->ShowDialog(this);
        if ( DR == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
        {
            o
            o
            o
```